# Microsoft Azure Deployment error

Tags: azure, deployment, virtual-machine

I am new to Microsoft Azure and I started deploying visual studio with windows 10 and tried all different versions (Enterprise, Professional). After 20 minutes deployment, I get same error which is as follows: These are in my audit log.

**OPERATION NAME** Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write
PROPERTIES: statusCode:Conflict statusMessage:{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","message":"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"OSProvisioningTimedOut","message":"OS Provisioning for VM 'ShaunPsm' did not finish in the allotted time. The VM may still finish provisioning successfully. Please check provisioning state later."}]}}

Hint: I started my subscription today. I also in my subscription I have visual studio enterprise.

Is there any solution? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign a storage account for your azure project. If not do that first.

Try taking package of the azure solution
Right click azure project > Package > 
select Cloud, Release and take package.
Then goto azure portal and create a cloud service, then upload package.
select check boxes to overwrite existing roles. then press OK.

Comment: Thanks Mathew , the problem was I had to configure storage from my storage accounts (in portal) first. I assumed it does it automatically when you create a new deployment.